# Proving the grammar S → SS+ | SS∗ | a is unambiguous

Tags: context-free, parsers, ambiguity

Consider the context-free grammar G = ({a, +, ∗}, {S}, {S → SS+ | SS∗ | a}, {S}) and consider the string aa+a* generated by this grammar.

Is this grammar unambiguous?

I have browsed the Internet and I have found that there is no standard procedure for proving if a grammar is unambiguous or not. But sometimes induction on length of the string or maybe length of the derivations works. I think in this question I can do something via length of sentential forms but I am not sure if its rigorous or not.

My approach: induction on length of sentential forms

Base case: length=1 then it has to be S -> a hence unambiguous.
Induction step: for length <= n assume all sentential forms are unambiguous.
Consider a sentential form ww'. So here w can be either S or a. If a then done since unique derivation else if S then only possibility is that there has to be SS+ or SS* hence we know S produces these unambiguously and the rest is unambiguous by hypothesis hence proved.

This seems more of a cyclic argument to me so I would be glad if someone could help me out.

By the way, what is the language generated by a grammar?

In this case, I think that it's the language that does postfix operation on addition and multiplication that is being described here. But how do we generalise for grammars?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Yes, the language consists of reversed Polish notations where each number is denoted by the single character "a".

Comment: I can derive aa in two ways.

Comment: I see… * and + are used as actual symbols instead of part of the grammar.

Comment: "there has to be SS+ or SS* hence we know S produces these unambiguously." Which S produces what? Had you specified clearly what are they referring to, you will see there is some significant gap.

Comment: Usually "SS+" means "one S, followed by one or more S", and "SS*" means "one S, followed by zero or more S". Put the '+' and '*' in quote to avoid confusion.

Comment: The three alternatives end in a different symbol, hence there is always only one way to reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### $L(G)$ is the set of all p-expressions

Let an operator mean either $+$ or $*$. In order to characterize the strings generated by $G$, we may observe the number of operators and the number of $a$'s in a string.

Call a string $w$ over alphabet $\{a, +, *\}$ a p-expression  if

- $w$ is non-empty,  and
- there are at least as many operators as $a$'s in each proper suffix of $w$ while there are one less operators than $a$'s in $w$. (In particular, $w$ ends with an operator and starts with two $a$'s unless $w=a$.)

**Claim**: $L(G)$ is the set of all p-expressions.
**Proof**: Use structural induction. This is an easy exercise for the readers.

#### $G$ is unambiguous

**Proof**: Let us show that $w\in L(G)$ has a unique parse tree using induction on $|w|$.

- Base case, $|w|=1$. Then $w$ must be $a$. $S\to a$ is the only derivation for $w$.
- As induction hypothesis, assume the proposition is true for $|w|\le n$.
  Let $|w|=n+1$. WLOG, suppose $w$ ends with $+$. So the first step in the derivation for $w$ must be $$S\to SS+.$$
  Let $w_1$ be the string produce by the first $S$ on the right hand side and $w_2$ be the string produced by the second $S$ so that $w=w_1w_2+$. Note that $w_1, w_2\in L(G)$.
  Scanning $w_1w_2+$ from right to left character by character, let us track the difference of the number of operators and the number of $a$'s scanned. The claim above implies the last scanned character of $w_2$ must be the character at which that difference have dropped to 0 for the first time.
  So $w_2$ is determined uniquely by $w$. Hence $w_1$ is also determined uniquely by $w$.
  By induction hypothesis, there is a unique parse tree for $w_1$ and for $w_2$. Hence, there is a unique parse tree for $w$. $\quad\checkmark$

#### Inspect $G$ reversed

Here is another way to show $G$ is unambiguous, which may appear simpler for readers with more experience.

Let $G^r$ be $G$ with production rules reversed, i.e.,
$$G^r=(\{a,+, *\}, \{S\}, \{S\to +SS, S\to *SS, s\to a\}, \{S\}).$$
It is easy to see that $G$ is unambiguous iff $G^r$ is unambiguous.

With some simple routine computation, we can obtain the $LL(1)$ parsing-table of $G^r$,
$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    &{\\\$} &+         & *           & a      \\\hline
S   &   &S\to +SS  &S\to *SS   & S\to a \\\hline
\end{array}$$
As an $LL(1)$ grammar, $G^r$ is unambiguous. Hence, $G$ is ambiguous as well.

More generally, we can prove that a context-free grammar is unambiguous if all production rules end with different terminals.

#### An exercise

Prove $(\{0, 1,+, *\},$ $\{S, B\},$ $\{S\to SS+,$ $S\to SS*,$ $S\to 
B,$ $B\to 0B,$ $B\to 1B,$ $B\to 0,$ $B\to 1\},$ $\{S\})$ is an unambiguous grammar.

Comment: John, maybe the exercise has a typo? The nonterminal B is not generating.

Comment: @Tonita, thanks, [updated](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/149028/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest another easy method to prove that the grammar $G$ is unambiguous. We can use the LR(0) parsing property to do so.

The language $L(G)$ is not prefix-free. If we add the endmarker $\\\$$ to the language, thus introducing a new initial nonterminal $S'$ and the rule $S'$ $\rightarrow$ $S$ $\\\$$ then the prefix property is satisfied. If the resulting grammar $G'$ is LR(0) then the initial grammar is necessarily unambiguous, otherwise we would get a parsing conflict for some word in $L(G')$. The LR(0)-property of $G'$ can be easily proven by constructing the corresponding finite state automaton.

Btw, this method does not provide a criterion of unambiguety, it gives only a sufficient condition. There are some unambiguous grammars that generate non-deterministic CFLs (the most famous example is the grammar generating even palindromes).

Comment: Nice, with endmarker added $G$ does become [LR(0)](http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/lr0.php?grammar=S+-%3E+T+s.%0AT+-%3E+T+T+%2A.%0AT+-%3E+T+T+%2B.)